# Is there a tool/command to reconnect a SSH

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I often need to ssh to a build machine (on ubuntu) for building software.
But sometime, my connection to the machine is disconnected (e.g. due to Wifi not stable).

Is there anyway I can 'reconnect my old ssh session? so that I can keep my build job?

Now, the build job on build machine still runs but i have no idea when it will end in my new ssh shell.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head I can think of two tools:

- [Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes, typically interactive shells. It allows you to disconnect from the server but keep your session running.
- [Mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/) Mobile shell, which is a remote terminal application that allows roaming, supports intermittent connectivity.

Screen has been around for a long time and I've personally used it several times. It's really handy. Mosh is the new kid on the block and looks really interesting. I haven't gotten around to test driving it yet.

Comment: +1 for `screen`. I actually have my login script configured to automatically start a `screen` session if one is not running, or reconnect to an existing one if there is one running. Just add `screen -aAxRUO` to the bottom of your `.profile` in your home directory on the server! This will even allow you to connect to the same SSH session from multiple computers at the same time.

Comment: @Darth Nice tip. Didn't now about the -aAxRUO switch :P

Comment: Well, it's more like 6 :P It basically says "Do whatever you have to to get me a screen session **now**", plus UTF-8 support.

Answer (score 2):

[tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) is another option to check out.

From the tmux homepage:

> tmux is a terminal multiplexer: it enables a number of terminals (or
>   windows), each running a separate program, to be created, accessed,
>   and controlled from a single screen. tmux may be detached from a
>   screen and continue running in the background, then later reattached.